# List the lines with the highest scores

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a file called `points.txt` and it contains the following table of data:

```
Jim:4
Tim:8
Lin:6
Tom:1
Esko:2
Jaska:5
Erkki:7
```

Now how can I list the following list in numerical order (highest first) or how can I list the three names with highest scores. I have tries the following by they don't seems to work

```
sort -n -k 1,1 points.txt
sort -n points.txt
sort -n ^: points.txt
```

Comment: Please use meaningful titles, not “meta-titles” like “Question about X”. We know you have a question, you're posting a question. The title should describe what your question is about, it should be the gist of your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you looking for the top 3

```
sort -k2,2rn -t: points.txt  | head -n 3 | cut -f1 -d:
```

`-k` specifies the sort field, the parts that follow indicate the following

`2,2` - sort key starts and ends at field `2`

`n`  - numeric sorting

`r` - reverse sorting

`-t` is used to specify the field separator, which in this case is `:`

Comment: could you explain this part more in details: -k2,2rn -t:

Comment: @cash, added some details. Try `man sort` and `info sort` on your installation for documentation